# Retrieving post tags from tables with relationships

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-schema

I am writting some blogging software for my assignment and I have a `posts` table, `tags` table and `post_tags`. `post_tags` exist to remove the many-to-many relationship (one post may have many tags and one tag may belong to many posts). Here's the fields for those tables:

posts

```
| p_id | title | clean_title | body | published | u_id |
```

tags

```
| t_id | name | slug |
```

post_tags

```
 | t_id | p_id |
```

Hopefully you can see what I've got going on here, tags are linked to posts using the `post_tags` table. Now, I want to retrieve `name` and `slug` from the `tags` table based on the `clean_title` field of the `posts` table. Basically, if I give the `clean_name`, I want all tags associated with that post. I know I have to use SQL JOINS, but I don't have much of an idea how to use them.

This is what I've tried:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, slug
                           FROM tags
                           LEFT JOIN post_tags ON posts.p_id=post_tags.p_id
                           LEFT JOIN tags ON post_tags.t_id=tags.t_id
                           WHERE posts.clean_title = ?
                           ORDER BY name DESC");
```

But I get this error: `Not unique table/alias: 'tags'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your first `JOIN` references `posts` but you don't use that table anywhere else. I suspect you meant:

```
     SELECT name, slug
     /* First table should have been `posts`? */
     FROM posts
     LEFT JOIN post_tags ON posts.p_id=post_tags.p_id
     LEFT JOIN tags ON post_tags.t_id=tags.t_id
     WHERE posts.clean_title = ?
     ORDER BY name DESC
```

Comment: Woopsie. Knew it would be something simple haha :P Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining `tags` twice.  Change the second `join` to join to the posts table:

```
SELECT tags.name, tags.slug
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN post_tags ON post_tags.t_id = tags.t_id
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.p_id = post_tags.p_id
WHERE posts.clean_title = ?
```

You can shorten the query with aliases like:

```
SELECT t.name, t.slug
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN post_tags pt ON pt.t_id = t.t_id
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.p_id = pt.p_id
WHERE p.clean_title = ?
```